# How can I get the value of a registry key using a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a batch script like this (which i was able to derive from [Open a file in Visual Studio at a specific line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350323/open-a-file-in-visual-studio-at-a-specific-line-number) ). Can any one tell me how to to pass the registry key of devenev i.e.( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\devenv.exe), so that i dont have to give the path as D:\Progra....and that it  can be run on any pc with visual studio installed. Thanks in advance.

`@echo off`

`cd /d D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE`

`devenv /Command "Edit.Goto 83" "E:\examples\A.cpp"`

`@echo off`

Comment: Why not just add the path D:\Program Files\...\IDE to your path environment variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445167/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-registry-key-from-within-a-batch-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=3*" %%x in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\devenv.exe"') do set DEVENV="%%x %%y"
%DEVENV% /Command "Edit.Goto 83" "E:\examples.A.cpp"
```

One caveat - if you have more than one edition of VS installed, this will launch the version which was most recently installed.

More generically:

```
set REGKEY="HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\BI\Science\AB\exenamehere.exe"
set CPPFILE=C:\SomePathHere\foo.cpp

for /f "tokens=3*" %%x in ('reg query "%REGKEY%"') do set EXE="%%x %%y"
%EXE% /AnyOtherParamsHere "%CPPFILE%"
```

You could also accept a command line argument like so (ideally there would be error handling as well).  %1 is the first argument, %2 would be the second, on up through 9.  Taking more than 9 parameters is certainly possible, but is beyond the scope of this question.

```
set REGKEY="HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\BI\Science\AB\exenamehere.exe"
set FILENAME=%1

for /f "tokens=3*" %%x in ('reg query "%REGKEY%"') do set EXE="%%x %%y"
%EXE% /AnyOtherParamsHere %FILENAME%
```

If the path to your file has spaces in it, you'll need to quote them when you run this batch file (e.g., `mybatch.cmd "C:\path with spaces\foo.cpp"`).

Also, don't forget to mark this as the answer if you've found it useful. :-)

Comment: If the path was not "E\examples.A.cpp" and if it was another registry key as HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\BI\Science\AB...how can i pass this into the code u've provided.Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey..i just moved my cpp into an examples folder and placed it into D:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC...Now the reg key name (folder) is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VideoLAN\VLC and i want the value data of the value name InstallDir..so that i can append the path \examples.A.cpp to the value data (which is actually a path -D:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC )..so that i can pass the path as %2..The code would be something like %DEVENV% /Command "Edit.Goto %1" "D:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\%2" but i dont want the path to be passed as D:\Pro...but the registry value of InstallDir.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN (
   'REG QUERY "HKLM\SSOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths" /v devenv.exe'
) DO (set vs9dir=%%B)
ECHO %vs9dir%
```

should return your value - in theory. I can't verify as I don't have VS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it might work:

```
for /f "tokens=3*" %%i in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\devenv.exe"^|find "<NO NAME>"') do set "key=%%j"
echo "%key%"
```