# Open File in Visual Studio 2012 as Preview Tab via DTE

Tags: .net, visual-studio, envdte

According to [Open a file in Visual Studio at a specific line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350323/open-a-file-in-visual-studio-at-a-specific-line-number) there is a way to get programmatic access to a file with a linenumber, I got that working, great.

Yet, I didn't find any docs for accessing the "Preview Tab feature" of VS2012 with DTE:
[image: Preview Tab in VS2012]

Could it be that DTE is now considered deprecated by MS (as not shipping with VS2012) and therefor VS automation reached EOL? That would be a shame. If not, how can I open a file as preview tab instead of normal file tab from e.g. commandline?