# How do I get the current excel filename in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I am writing a VTSO application that should work across multiple excel document templates.  I want the add in to check the document and attempt to select the one the user is using, however I cannot figure out how to grab the current filename in c# using VTSO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example:

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Foo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var excelApplication = (Excel.Application)CustomMarshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
            var currentWorkbook = excelApplication.ActiveWorkbook;
            Console.WriteLine("Current active Excel Workbook: " + currentWorkbook.Name); // or FullName to get full path to opened file
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

`CustomMarshal` and `GetActiveObject()` explanations can be found here:
[No definition found for GetActiveObject from System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010510/no-definition-found-for-getactiveobject-from-system-runtime-interopservices-mars)