# LinqPad 7 - C# - Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.GetObject

Tags: linqpad

**Solved by Comment from Joe Albahari**

In LinQPad 7 I try to connect to an open Excel Application.
In  C# .net this is easy done by eg:

`public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApplication; ExcelApplication = (Application)Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.GetObject(Class: "Excel.Application");`

With references to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and Microsoft.VisualBasic

In LinQPad 7 I tried the same but ExcelApplication is null (Yes Excel is open!)
References are set and Namespace imported.
It shows no error, just does not connect.

What am I doing wrong?
(The example from LinqPad for Excel creates a new excel application.

thanks for any help

Comment: Does the following help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65496277

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried the Marshall approach but failed at GetActiveObject like in the article. But I could not find the solution in SO which is given in this Article by the Marshal2 Class. Works like a charm. Tx again.