# VB.NET GetObject NET 6.0 COM Issue while there is no issue with Framework 4.8

Tags: vb.net, .net-6.0, catia

I have a very simple code below to get CATIA object. When I create a project with `NET Framework 4.8`, there is no issue, I can get the CATIA application and start working with it. However, when I use `NET 6.0` project, I get `“Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

```
Dim CATIA as Object
CATIA = GetObject(,"CATIA.APPLICATION")
MessageBox.Show(CATIA.ActiveDocument.Name)
```

Does anyone have some idea if this can be fixed with `NET 6.0` or I will stuck with `NET Framework`?

Comment: Try to use Marshall ?  Dim CATIA As INFITF.Application
CATIA = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("CATIA.Application").

Comment: I'd highly recommend you move your .Net Framework code into .Net 6 Core. Almost everything is the catered for, alas with slightly different implementations but its all well documented. Keeping a codebase with a mix of frameworks isn't best business practice and often leads to dependency rot. Also upgrading it to core will mean you can run it on Linux or Mac.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, I am moving away from Framework but I encounter the very 1st issue - this one.

Comment: @Disvoys, there is no ‘GetActiveObject’ - I am using NET 6.0

Comment: Try to make your own function Marshall. You will find this function easily in Google. Then you will have thé GetActiveObject. I'm also using .net 6. If it Can help, a sample : https://chat.openai.com/share/3f361a43-31b7-4093-ad96-5728ae7df5e9

Comment: @N.TW12  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65496277/19028100