# NET (Core) COM connection to Catia v5/v6 issue

Tags: vb.net, catia

I am trying to move way from Net Framework but I cannot use COM with the new NET. As I understand, Net does not have the `GetObject/GetActiveObject` like Net Framework so we need to implement our `Marshal` - which I used the code here
`https://chat.openai.com/share/3f361a43-31b7-4093-ad96-5728ae7df5e9`

Issue: I can get the `CATIA.APPLICATION` but I cannot operate or get any property

```
Dim CATIA = Marshal2.GetActiveObject("CATIA.APPLICATION")
Dim caption as string = CATIA.Caption ~~~~> this returns the generic error `HRESULT E_FAIL"
```

I wonder if anyone has successfully used Net Core to make the connection? I would like to note that Catia is installed on remote machine and I have no right to install Visual Studio on the remote machine that why my code must use `GetObject` equivalent.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Security

Private Class Marshal2
    Friend Const OLEAUT32 As String = "oleaut32.dll"
    Friend Const OLE32 As String = "ole32.dll"

    <SecurityCritical>
    Public Shared Function GetActiveObject(ByVal progID As String) As Object
        Dim obj As Object = Nothing
        Dim clsid As Guid

        ' Appelez d'abord CLSIDFromProgIDEx, puis revenez à CLSIDFromProgID si
        ' CLSIDFromProgIDEx n'existe pas.
        Try
            CLSIDFromProgIDEx(progID, clsid)
        Catch ex As Exception
            CLSIDFromProgID(progID, clsid)
        End Try

        GetActiveObject(clsid, IntPtr.Zero, obj)
        Return obj
    End Function

    <DllImport(OLE32, PreserveSig:=False)>
    <ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)>
    <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
    <SecurityCritical>
    Private Shared Sub CLSIDFromProgIDEx(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal progId As String, ByRef clsid As Guid)
    End Sub

    <DllImport(OLE32, PreserveSig:=False)>
    <ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)>
    <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
    <SecurityCritical>
    Private Shared Sub CLSIDFromProgID(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal progId As String, ByRef clsid As Guid)
    End Sub

    <DllImport(OLEAUT32, PreserveSig:=False)>
    <ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)>
    <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
    <SecurityCritical>
    Private Shared Sub GetActiveObject(ByRef rclsid As Guid, ByVal reserved As IntPtr, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)> ByRef ppunk As Object)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The _Marshal2_ code is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/65496277/10024425

Answer (score 0):

In c#. Convert it to VB.net.

Using Activator:

```
Catia = (INFITF.Application)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("CATIA.Application"));
```

Using Marshall:

```
            Catia = (INFITF.Application)Marshal2.GetActiveObject("Catia.Application");


private static class Marshal2
        {
            internal const string OLE32 = "ole32.dll";
            internal const string OLEAUT32 = "oleaut32.dll";

            [SecurityCritical]
            public static object GetActiveObject(string progID)
            {
                object obj = null;
                Guid clsid;

                try
                {
                    CLSIDFromProgIDEx(progID, out clsid);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    CLSIDFromProgID(progID, out clsid);
                }

                GetActiveObject(ref clsid, IntPtr.Zero, out obj);
                return obj;
            }

            [DllImport(OLE32, PreserveSig = false)]
            [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
            [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
            [SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
            private static extern void CLSIDFromProgID([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string progId, out Guid clsid);

            [DllImport(OLE32, PreserveSig = false)]
            [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
            [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
            [SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
            private static extern void CLSIDFromProgIDEx([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string progId, out Guid clsid);

            [DllImport(OLEAUT32, PreserveSig = false)]
            [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
            [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
            [SecurityCritical]
            private static extern void GetActiveObject(ref Guid rclsid, IntPtr reserved, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object ppunk);
        }
```